# Dynamic Wordpress background

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a dynamic background for my wordpress site. I want the 'featured image' to be the background of the jumbotron (on the header of the page).

This is what I have so far but I can't get it to link properly. I know I'm missing some important code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="jumbotron row" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url ?>');">
    <header>
        <div class="navbar navbar-custom">
          ... etc ....
```

**CSS**

```
.jumbotron { 
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 125px 0 75px 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: So what is ur question or problem?

Comment: how can I get the 'featured image' of the post as the background for jumbotron

Comment: Make sure the variable `$thumbnail_url` contains a correct value. Also add `;` after `echo` like this `<?php echo $thumbnail_url; ?>`

Comment: @user3550879 whats the problem with ur implementation? have u inspected the DOM to see if the `background-image:` has a value? if so, whats that?

Comment: post your rendered html. so that we can easily identify the problem.

Comment: unfortunately its on my local server through xampp

Comment: Post your html, not a link to a page. Try `Ctrl+U` in your browser

Comment: By now it is not clear what's your problem. The background image does not randomize, does not changing or does not appear at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Check Inspect element  or view page source the correct path is calling or not,

ex:

   get_stylesheet_directory_uri()/images/imagesname.jpg;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image is not being rendered,I suggest you to check whether the $thumbnail_url is populated with the correct value.Then you may inspect the `<div>` tag in the front-end to determine issues with concatenation.

Comment: I believe we have a nice comment section under the question for such suggestions.

Comment: sry abt that, i was unable to comment due to my reputation points so i had to post it as an answer.